# Can I have nested ng-include's?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a template that is inserted via `ng-include` and that template also has an `ng-include`. The inner `ng-incude` is not being shown. Why?

Main Template:

```
<div ng-include src="'views/outer.html'"></div>
```

views/outer.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    // Stuff
    <div ng-include src="'views/inner.html'"></div> // not being shown
    // More stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if you have any JavaScript errors?  An error might prevent the remainder of the Angular (or any JS) code from running.

Comment: Also see the console for path issues. Make sure the partial exist at the location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted should work so the problem is probably situated somewhere else.

One of the reasons could be that a JavaScript error is thrown somewhere else or that no items are found in the scope. Make sure to check the browser console.

Here is a working version of your code for your convenience:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pCTInrtITqHraC1hPyZH?p=preview

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

ng-include is a directive. Your view/outer.html should do like this:

```
$parent.items
```

Because directive not inherit parent automatically.